# Hibernate fetch only first row ,using only in .hbm.xml?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I want fetch first row only using hbm.xml , there is contrainst that without HQL .

```
Object = getSession().createCriteria(BeanClass.class) 
        .add(Restrictions.eq().UniqueResults();
```

Comment: You cannot do that in a mapping that is part of the query execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set criteria.setMaxResults(1); it will return only one row

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = createQuery("FROM nayO WHERE NO =:RelNo AND CODE =:CntryCode AND STATUS !='D'");
        query.setParameter("No", rgRelNo);
        query.setParameter("ode", Code);
        return (nayVO) query.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
```

this will gives the first row which is unique result .

Comment: Note that it might lead to inconsistent results, incase if there are more than records exists with the `query`  `where` condition. What is your use-case?